# In a groovy script for a DataGen property get the corresponding Property name

Tags: soapui, ready-api

I have a Ready API DataGen step that applies default values to the output of a DataSource step. Any given property will use the same name in both steps.

When processing the property "Address.AddressLine1" the values are in retrieved from "#DataSource#Address.AddressLine1" and stored in "#DataGen#Address.AddressLine1".

To avoid copy-paste errors I want to write reusable code but my current code requires a individualize property name for each instance.

[image]

DataGen stores a separate groovy script for each property. If an instance of a script could retrieve the name of its companion property/label then the context expand part can be genericized and I will avoid typos in property names.

a made up example would be:

```
def key = String.format('${#DataSource#%s}',context.parent.getLabel())
```

I have looked at the runtime properties of context and currentStep objects as well as the javadoc and have not found a way to match up a script instance with the property that will be assigned the generated value.

Comment: If you already have `DataSource` step, then why `DataGen` step? Not redundant?

Comment: mostly a design choice that enables me check the data before consumption rather than assume the correct defaults are in place and that no "blanks" exist.